# Сжатие файлов на Java EE сервере

Tags: java, кэширование

Надо на лету сжимать и кэшировать js/css. Как это можно сделать, какие есть готовые решения, что можно почитать ?

Comment: nginx подойдёт? Умеет gzip и кеширование.

Comment: Спасибо, но уже подключил yuicompressor, кэширую с помощью ehcache.